# Shell script: starting new terminal and using file to provide standard input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a scenario where I need to start a python script in a new terminal. This script takes (waits for) user input at various steps in its execution. I want to automate it and provide all the sequence of inputs in a file. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$ cat commands.txt
1\r
2\r
3\r

$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -- python3 test.py 1<commands.txt
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to do this correctly ? I'm also not sure if using '\r' to separate each input in my commands.txt file is the right approach.

Comment: Maybe `gnome-terminal -e 'cat commands.txt | python3 test.py'`

Comment: maybe `gnome-terminal -e 'python3 test.py <commands.txt; read -p "press Enter to continue" var'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's a [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat); you are looking for `gnome-terminal -e 'python3 test.py < commands.txt'`. And no, `\r` doesn't do anything useful here, unless your Python program does something interesting with a literal backslash character followed by `r`. Just the newlines should suffice.